# Перехват ссылок

Tags: delphi, ссылки

Вопрос в следующем: необходимо отловить ссылки с определенным адресом, и их загружать в `webbrowser` внутри программы. Остальные ссылки должны открываться как положено, в браузере по умолчанию.
Т.е. если асей/скайпом на интернет странице т.д. переходят по ссылке с нужным адресом, она перехватывается программой.

Answer (score 4):

Самый тривиальный способ, который, предположительно, будет работать для вариантов `ася и скайп` - написать простенькую *"программу-прокси"*, которая принимает некоторую ссылку как параметр командной строки, и дальше *(в зависимости от того, нужный адрес, или нет)* делают с ней, что хотят, например, пересылают дефолтному браузеру.

После того, как эта программа написана, она в `file associations` вешается на дефолтное поведение для нужных протоколов `(http, https, ... )` и все хорошо.

---

Перехватить обработку ссылки в браузере - задача очень нетривиальная, и, что самое неприятное, браузеро-зависимая. Максимум, что можно сделать безболезненно - это перехватить какойнить `receive` библиотеки `winsock`, и, в случае, если приходит `HTTP-response` от нужной страницы, то **дублировать открытие этой страницы руками и в той программе, в которой вам нужно.**

Но это не меняет того факта, что у вас все еще будет висеть открытым это окно в браузере, которое тоже необходимо закрыть. Сделать это можно по-разному, вот здесь как раз и появляется **браузеро-зависимость**.

Сэмулить `Ctrl-W`, воспользоваться `Greasemonkey`, если он установлен, написать плагин. Решения есть, но, они, к сожалению, либо корявые *(как `Ctrl-W)*, либо интрузивные, как все остальные.